# KeyError: '' running flask-socketio gevent nginx server

Tags: nginx, flask, redis, gevent, flask-socketio

I keep getting the following error when running an application on flask-socketio server with gevent and nginx:

```
maze.service - maze game
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/maze.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-07-29 18:50:57 UTC; 41min ago
   Main PID: 86974 (gunicorn)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1130)
     Memory: 79.4M
        CPU: 9.185s
     CGroup: /system.slice/maze.service
             ├─86974 /home/ubuntu/maze/mazenv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/maze/mazenv/bin/gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 --timeout 600 --bind unix:maze.so>
             └─86976 /home/ubuntu/maze/mazenv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/maze/mazenv/bin/gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 --timeout 600 --bind unix:maze.so>

Jul 29 18:50:57 ip-172-31-22-170 gunicorn[86976]: [2023-07-29 18:50:57 +0000] [86976] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 86976
Jul 29 18:54:01 ip-172-31-22-170 gunicorn[86976]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jul 29 18:54:01 ip-172-31-22-170 gunicorn[86976]:   File "/home/ubuntu/maze/mazenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 999, in handle_one_response
Jul 29 18:54:01 ip-172-31-22-170 gunicorn[86976]:     self.run_application()
Jul 29 18:54:01 ip-172-31-22-170 gunicorn[86976]:   File "/home/ubuntu/maze/mazenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geventwebsocket/handler.py", line 75, in run_application
Jul 29 18:54:01 ip-172-31-22-170 gunicorn[86976]:     self.run_websocket()
Jul 29 18:54:01 ip-172-31-22-170 gunicorn[86976]:   File "/home/ubuntu/maze/mazenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geventwebsocket/handler.py", line 54, in run_websocket
Jul 29 18:54:01 ip-172-31-22-170 gunicorn[86976]:     del self.server.clients[self.client_address]
Jul 29 18:54:01 ip-172-31-22-170 gunicorn[86976]: KeyError: ''
Jul 29 18:54:01 ip-172-31-22-170 gunicorn[86976]: 2023-07-29T18:54:01Z {'HTTP_HOST': 'www.mnrity.io', (hidden keys: 39)} failed with KeyError
```

I can't figure out where this error is coming from